# XML XPath find all nodes with attribute and his parent

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to write XPath query that will return from this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<contents> 
  <content type="menu_0" nested="yes"> 
    <content type="name" lang="pol"><![CDATA[PIES]]></content>  
    <content type="menu_1" nested="yes"> 
      <content type="name" lang="pol"><![CDATA[Thing1]]></content>  
      <content type="name" lang="pol"><![CDATA[Thing2]]></content>  
      <content type="name" lang="pol"><![CDATA[Thing3]]></content> 
    </content> 
  </content> 
</contents>
```

something like this

```
PIES\Thing1
PIES\Thing2
PIES\Thing3
```

Can someone help?:)

Comment: This is not a very well designed structure for parsing.  Will here be multiple instances of these groups of <content> elements under <contents>?

Comment: I can get the child nodes extracted with //content[@type='menu_1']/*/text()  However, I don't think you can pre-append the "PIES" string with straigt xpath.

Comment: @OldProgrammer im just trying to process existing xmls but i want to make it fast:)

Answer (score 1):

Using **XPath 1.0** you cannot get all the nodes as desired with `PIES\` concatenated to `Thing*`, you need to use three xpath expressions like below :

```
concat( //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='name']/text(), '\',  //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='menu_1']/content[1]/text())

concat( //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='name']/text(), '\',  //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='menu_1']/content[2]/text())

concat( //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='name']/text(), '\',  //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='menu_1']/content[3]/text())
```

With **XPath 2.0**, you could use a for-loop to return the list in one xpath expression as below:

```
for $thing in //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='menu_1']/content/text()
   return concat( //content[@type='menu_0']/content[@type='name']/text(), '\',  $thing )
```

Comment: thanks it worked its not perfect but its start for me:)